# d3 - create multi column data dynamically using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two date. And i wanted to create a array with the number of days between them.

I've done it successfully. And here's the code.

Code :

```
var data = [];
var start = new Date('2014-02-01');
var end = new Date('2014-02-28');

var timeDiff = Math.abs(end.getTime() - start.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

```
for ( var i = 0; i < diffDays; ++i ) {
    var date = new Date(start)
    date.setDate(start.getDate() + i)

    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

    formattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy

    data.push(formattedDate)
}
```

And i got the array for the number of days between it.

But now i'm looking a bit forward.

I wanted to add another column.

Suppose i have these following date.
`['2014-02-05', '2014-02-10']`. I wanted to add another column like date2 which will have `-` value for all the rows except the row where the date generated dynamically and the above two date matches.

Someone please help me in creating data for two column dynamically.

Expected Output :

```
{ "date": "2014-02-01", "date2": "-" },
{ "date": "2014-02-02", "date2": "-" }
{ "date": "2014-02-03", "date2": "2014-02-03" }
{ "date": "2014-02-04", "date2": "-" }
{ "date": "2014-02-05", "date2": "2014-02-05" }
{ "date": "2014-02-06", "date2": "-" }
```

Comment: Can you not use the following, `data.push([formattedDate,"-"])` so that another column is added to the data.

Comment: Result i get is a array of single column with `date` and `-` repeated alternatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var data = [];
var start = new Date('2014-02-01');
var end = new Date('2014-02-28');
var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d');
var specialDates = ['2014-02-05', '2014-02-10'];

var newData = d3.time.day.range(start, end).map(
    function(d){
        var thisDateString = dateFormat(d);
        if (specialDates.indexOf(thisDateString) < 0)
            return {'date':thisDateString, 'date2':'-'}
        else
           return {'date':thisDateString, 'date2':thisDateString}
    }
)
```

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lfuj/)

We are using `d3.time.day.range(start, end)` to give us an array of days. Then by using `.map` we create a new array. **What are the values of this shiny new array?** Whatever is retuned for each item in the original array when passed into the function we define (so anything we want).

Comment: `specialDates.indexOf(thisDateString)` this must return 0 or 1 i guess so. Because only 2 date we have in that variable. And how it's getting mapped to it exactly? And i guess this is not stored to data variable.

Comment: See documentation of [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of dates easily with d3

```
d3.time.day.range(start, end)
```

You can use any of the intervals in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals#wiki-interval) which currently are

- second, minute, hour, day, week, month, year
- sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday

Comment: I wanted to create two columns. One with the date of start and end. And other with with `-` values for all the rows execpt the rows where the given date and date in array matches.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that. Regardless the helper function will reduce your code.

Comment: I'm not worried about the code length. I now wanted to create two column data using `data.push`. Can you help if you can?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do. Would you mind amending your question with example JSON of what you are trying to output?

Comment: Also complexity is the route of evil (sorry, bugs), I would strongly advice to refactor to use `interval.range()`